# How to convert this string to a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting this error when I try to `JSON.parse` this string `"['Answer 1', 'Answer 2']"`

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
    at Object.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

Can anybody tell me how to do it?

Comment: That is not JSON. Hence why you get the error. Quotes need to be `"` not `'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace all single quote(`'`) into double quote(`"`) to parse to javascript array.

```js
const input = "['Answer 1', 'Answer 2']";
const output = JSON.parse(input.replaceAll("'", '"'));
console.log(output);
```